# How to handle number of activities with SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have one Activity, I created class called DatabaseHelper that extends SQLiteOpenHelper,
now when I want to use it (has I see in many simple examples) I need to have new SQLiteDatabase Object & implement insert, update, delete... in my Activity code.

What is the right design if I want to work through database with number of activities and to create DatabaseHelper  just once, for all the activities will work with it.(and not have duplicate code.

simply: what is the right classes SQLite structure for number of Activities

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Just use one DatabaseHelper throughout your application, there's no profit in repeating yourself.

Comment: 1. But if i need to insert data to database from number of activities
i will create new object from DatabaseHelper in the other activities??

2. is it right to put the sql methods (insert,update..) in th DatabaseHelper class??

Comment: Just create your implementation of DatabaseHelper and use this class in all of your activities.

Answer (score 0):

Make your `DatabaseHelper` a singleton across your entire application's lifecycle. Check out my blog post on the topic:

### [Correctly Managing Your SQLite Database](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/correctly-managing-your-sqlite-database.html)

Comment: Hi thanks, greate blog!
i understood how to write the DatabaseHelper with singleton, i did it.
now where in the program i write the sql methods (insert, update..)?

i tried to open new SqlService class but i cant use the DatabaseHelper from there (context)

wherer i should write my sql code? what is the right design??

Thanks

Comment: Use `DatabaseHelper mHelper = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(context)` to get the singleton `DatabaseHelper` instance. Then use `SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWriteableDatabase` (or `getReadableDatabase`). Then you can make calls to `db.insert(...)`, `db.update(...)`, etc. I am assuming of course that your `DatabaseHelper` class `extends SQLiteOpenHelper`.

Comment: Yes i extends SQLiteOpenHelper.
db.insert(...), db.update(..),..etc
i implement on my Activity class??
exmp: if i have 3 Activity classes i implemnt db.insert in every Activity i need it?


or i open another class that contain all of those implementations?